# What is the default variable_scope in Tensorflow?

Tags: variables, tensorflow, machine-learning, scope

What is the default global `variable_scope` in Tensorflow? How can I inspect the object? Does anyone have ideas about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, there's no *global variable scope for all variables*. If you run

```
x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x')
```

from the top level of your script, a new variable `x` without a variable scope will be created in the default graph.

However, the situation is a bit different for [`tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) function:

```
x = tf.get_variable(name='x')
```

The first thing it does is calls [`tf.get_variable_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable_scope) function, which returns the *current variable scope*, which in turn looks up the scope from the local stack:

```
def get_variable_scope():
  """Returns the current variable scope."""
  scope = ops.get_collection(_VARSCOPE_KEY)
  if scope:  # This collection has at most 1 element, the default scope at [0].
    return scope[0]
  scope = VariableScope(False)
  ops.add_to_collection(_VARSCOPE_KEY, scope)
  return scope
```

Note that this stack can be empty and in this case, a new scope is simply created and pushed on top of the stack.

If *this* is the object you need, you can access it just by calling:

```
scope = tf.get_variable_scope()
```

from the top level, or by going to `ops.get_collection(_VARSCOPE_KEY)` directly if you're inside a scope already. This is exactly the scope that a new variable will get by a call to `tf.get_variable()` function. It's an ordinary instance of class [`tf.VariableScope`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/VariableScope) that you can easily inspect.