# tf.train.init_from_checkpoint does not initialize variables created with tf.Variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

It seems that `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` initalizes variables created via `tf.get_variable` but *not*  those created via `tf.Variable`.

For example, let's create two variables and save them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.Variable(1.0, name='foo')
tf.get_variable('bar',initializer=1.0)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  saver.save(sess, './model', global_step=0)
```

If I load them again via a `tf.train.Saver`, everything works fine: variables are loaded back to 1 even though they are initialized at zero here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

foo = tf.Variable(0.0, name='foo')
bar = tf.get_variable('bar', initializer=0.0)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, './model-0')
  print(f'foo: {foo.eval()}  bar: {bar.eval()}')
  # foo: 1.0  bar: 1.0
```

However if I use `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` I get

```
import tensorflow as tf

foo = tf.Variable(0.0, name='foo')
bar = tf.get_variable('bar', initializer=0.0)
tf.train.init_from_checkpoint('./model-0', {'/':'/'})
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print(f'foo: {foo.eval()}  bar: {bar.eval()}')
  # foo: 0.0  bar: 1.0
```

`bar` is set back to 1 as expected but `foo` remains at 0.

Is this the intended behavior? If so, why?

Comment: As no one seems to answer, I'll try to fix my previous attempt. It was mostly  superficial and not to the point. Hope it makes sense now

Comment: @Sharky your answer points to the code where that happens -- indeed it has to happen somewhere -- but it does not answer my question about the rationale of this choice. For all I know, this could be a bug, and your answer does not shed any light on that.

Comment: I update once again, sorry for having hard time making my point

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is intended. This behaviour is described in `_init_from_checkpoint` method, which iterates over assignment map when loading variables to restore.

```
 for tensor_name_in_ckpt, current_var_or_name in sorted(
      six.iteritems(assignment_map)):
    var = None
```

It first sets variable it's going to restore to `None` and will reset in to current variable name if one of several conditions is met. In this particular case, loop contains statement

`if "/" in current_var_or_name`

So, it will load variables from a dictionary `store_vars`, created earlier. It was created right after `_init_from_checkpoint` checks whether current variable from assignment map is `tf.Variable`, which is False at this time.

```
 if _is_variable(current_var_or_name) or (
        isinstance(current_var_or_name, list)
        and all(_is_variable(v) for v in current_var_or_name)):
      var = current_var_or_name
    else:
      store_vars = vs._get_default_variable_store()._vars
```

`store_vars` is created by internal class `_VariableStore`, more precisely, by it's `_get_default_variable_store()` method. This class uses `get_variable` as variable constructor. Because of the fact that `tf.Variable` doesn't have default scope, and `tf.get_variable` first calls tf.get_variable_scope(), which returns the current variable scope. 'foo' is outside of this scope. Besides `tf.Variable` will create a new variable every time it is called and doesn't allow sharing.

`store_vars` is constructed from default scope members and therefore, it contains only 'bar' variable, and `foo` is added to variables collection later with `tf.Variable` op.

However, if `assignment_map` will contain `{'foo':foo, 'bar':bar}`, the abovementioned for `_init_from_checkpoint` will find these variables and load them. So in this case your code will ouput `foo: 1.0  bar: 1.0`

You can find code in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py

and
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py
Also see this answer [What is the default variable_scope in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870535/what-is-the-default-variable-scope-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Yes, it does not allow sharing -- why would that imply that it could not be restored? After all, `tf.Variable` *does* get restored by a `tf.train.Saver.restore` as I show in my second example.

Comment: Because `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` replaces tf.Variable with `tf.get_variable` initializers so they could be load from a checkpoint file. As per https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_utils.py

Comment: So why is the initializer not being replaced in the case of a `tf.Variable`?

Comment: Because `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint` ignores `tf.Variable`. I'll update answer with a little clarification.